# isset - "name" when using AJAX request rather than form submit

Tags: php, ajax

When submitting a form, I can use

```
if (isset($_POST['login-submit'])) {
```

How can I set a 'name', like 'login-submit' in the example above, when instead using an AJAX request like this?:

```
xhttp.open("POST", "includes/stats.inc.php", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: You could check for `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST")` rather than this way.

Comment: You can send params through the `send()` method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send

Comment: Thanks droopsnoot, I'll use that. Now I'm stuck on passing params with send(). Have detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62150613/xmlhttprequest-passing-parameter-to-php-file