# XMLHttpRequest -- passing parameter to PHP file

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

I've got the following XMLHttpRequest:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "includes/stats.inc.php", true);
xhttp.send("date=" + date);
```

I want to pass the date variable through to the php file which does some stuff.

I have double checked and the php file does some stuff [without the date variable] if I 'call' it using a form:

```
<form action="includes/stats.inc.php" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="login-submit">test</button>
</form>
```

But it's my understanding I need to use an XMLHttpRequest to pass the variable. I've searched and tried various ways of doing it and it doesn't seem to work. When doing:

```
xhttp.responseText
```

it just returns the HTML code.
Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: not really clear on what you wanna do there.

Comment: @Mox, I want to run a php script in the file 'includes/stats.inc.php', sending in the parameter date. I believe I should be using XHttp to do this? But it doesn't work, I don't understand why, and the responseText just returns the HTML code of page the request is sent from

Comment: does your backend api able to handle this variable? php is meant for server side programming. Therefore to embed the variable in the php template, your endpoint must know how to process it.

Comment: you will need to share your php code.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be doing anything with the PHP file at all, even if I leave send() blank, and the php file just contains
```
header("Location: ../index.php?result=else");
  exit();
```
It doesn't do anything, unlike if I do post through the form in my second piece of code above ^

Comment: then how does your php know what is the variable to print?

Comment: @Mox I was doing ```$dateToday = $_POST['date'];```, but if I leave the send() param blank and just test with having the php file do ```header("Location: ../index.php?result=else"); exit();```, it still doesn't do anything at all

Comment: @Mox, silly me, I just realised that it IS working -- the response text IS the 
``` 
"Location: ../index.php?result=else" 
```
, right? In that case, how can I do a redirect in the php in this instance?